# How to get a String's Id or Parent using Auto It

Tags: windows, autoit

Similar Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234120/how-to-find-string-in-a-window-using-autoit) (Unanswered, because it is not specific enough)

In the original question someone answering it asked for a picture to help them identify how to help.
Here is a picture of the App I am trying to automate.

[Ascii To MetaStock Utility 2.0.0.835](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmYcO.png)

Specifically I'm having trouble Reading the bottom bar that says "ready" in the picture. I need to be able to tell when that bar changes to "conversion finished". I'm not sure how to do that and following along with a couple tutorials did not work for me. They were all focused on getting text when you know the Id of the frame already.

Currently My script looks like this (with no attempt to get the string & my local path removed)

```
Run"C:/PATH/A2MS.exe"
WinWaitActive(Ascii to MetaStock Utility 2.0.0.835)
Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")
```

In case want to test your solution or need access to the app to answer my question.
The app may be downloaded for free if you register an account, it is from [EODdata.com](http://eoddata.com/).

Any help or links to appropriate articles/tutorials are appreciated.

EDIT:
Using WinGetText() shows statusStrip1 and menuStrip1 where the string I want to compare should be. I don't know enough about AutoIT to know what that means.

Edit 2: Detecting whether or not the convert button is enabled would also allow me to shut it down when it is finished, and would be a valid answer to this question. WinGetText() shows c&onvert where the button would be.

Comment: AutoIt comes with a small tool called Au3Info.exe that shows the properties of screen controls you hover over. But please keep in mind that only native Windows controls will display properly.

Answer (score -1):

Retrieves the text from a standard status bar control.

```
StatusbarGetText ( "title" [, "text" [, part = 1]] )
```

Extracts a number of characters from a string.

```
StringMid ( "string", start [, count = -1] )
```

Returns a number of characters from the left-hand side of a string.

```
StringSplit ( "string", "delimiters" [, flag = 0] )
```

Checks if a string contains a given substring.

```
StringInStr ( "string", "substring" [, casesense = 0 [, occurrence = 1 [, start = 1 [, count]]]] )
```

Returns the string representation of an expression.

```
StringSplit ( "string", "delimiters" [, flag = 0] )
```

Checks if a string contains a given substring.

```
StringInStr ( "string", "substring" [, casesense = 0 [, occurrence = 1 [, start = 1 [, count]]]]` )
```

Comment: I tried ConsoleWrite(StatusbarGetText("Ascii to MetaStock Utility 2.0.0.835","",1)) but it doesn't write anything to the console. I think it might not be a standard status bar. Or am I doing it wrong. I tried a few other part numbers but nothings worked so far.